# DockbarX inside AWN, preview window shifted on dual-screen after shifting from single-screen

Tags: awn, dockbarx

I've been running dockbarx in AWN for sometime now. I started using dual-screens and started seeing a problem with the window preview. When I hover over the dockbarx icon to see the preview it appears on the other monitor.

I'm assuming that this is due to it still thinking there is only one monitor. I was hoping someone new of a gconf-editor setting that I could set with the rest of my screen that changes my laptop from internal monitor to my dual-screen setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a fix, I'm afraid - I have the same issue; and I've found that selecting a new theme and applying it sorts it too:

- Right-click handle of dockbar
- Select properties
- Choose a new theme
- Apply

Answer (score 0):

DockbarX has some bugs when it comes to dualscreen since I have no change to test the code myself and have to rely on bug reports from others. I've heard about this problem before (with dockbarx in normal panel, not awn) but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Is there any additional data I can provide to you that might help you trace this issue?